# Why ComboBox in actinoscript 3 take so much space to show all its items?

Tags: flash

```
<div style="background-color:blue">
<object height="300px" width="100px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/flash/cameralist.swf" id="cameralist" style="visibility: visible;"></object>
</div>
```

[image]

It's taking up `300px` ,but actually only the upside `150px` is in use.

How to show all its items while keeping the page UI normal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's just the specification of the component you are using, which has fixed dimensions. If you have access to its source code try to play with width, height (like setting them to 100% if this is Flex).

Comment: Yes I have access to the DOM,but it disappears if I set the `height` to `100%`